# Line breaks in django po files

Tags: django, django-templates, po

How can I use line breaks in translation strings inside **.po** files?
Currently I added "**\n**" and used `{{msg|linebreaks}}` in my template, but the string is printed in one single line... how can I print it on multiple lines?

Comment: {% blocktrans %}
                 Translate this string
                 {% plural %}
                 And this plural string
          {% endblocktrans %}

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want HTML output. In such case, it would be better to include HTML tags in the string:

```
{% blocktrans %}
First line<br/>
Second line
{% endblocktrans %}
```

If you are looking for something else, please describe better what you are actually trying to achieve.

Update:

If the lines are independent, it might be even better to actually split them up:

```
{% trans "First line" %}
<br/>
{% trans "Second line" %}
```

Comment: Yes, I want html output... but honestly I don't like to embed html tags in localized strings :P

Answer (score 1):

bit late, but maybe helps someone, add your translation like this:

po file

```
msgid "_your_msgid"
msgstr "first line\nsecond line"
```

template

```
{% trans '_your_msgid' as local_var %}
{{ local_var|linebreaksbr }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&#10;` character both in django template file and your `.po` files

Like this `.po`:

```
msgid "Psycological&#10;aid"
msgstr "Психологическая&#10;помощь"
```

django template:

```
{% trans 'Psycological&#10;aid' %}
```

Containing block should have `white-space: pre-line;` css rule